# does for keyword understand that a string is an iteration?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Question :
" Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order."

Code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
hh = list()
for sen in fh:
    sen=sen.split()
    for element in sen:
        if element not in hh:
            hh.append(element)
            hh.sort()        
print(hh)
```

I want to make sure that  I understood the code. So first we took the file name then opened it then we created an empty list then we split the strings into a list and then we checked if the elements in sen is in the empty list we created and then we appended it and printed.
Also, I have a question when using the for keyword, does the for keyword understand that each word in the file is an iteration even before splitting it??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to read up on what [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) and [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) are in Python. `for` loops don't understand anything per se. They essentially just call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on an iterator until [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) is raised. It's up to the iterator in question to decide what should be yielded during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Python str.split() documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") #-- user enters name of a file
fh = open(fname) #-------------------- open the file
hh = list() #------------------------- create an empty list
for sen in fh: #---------------------- loop through lines in the file
    sen=sen.split() #----------------- split the line into words
    for element in sen: #------------- loop through words in the line
        if element not in hh: #------- if word is not in the list of unique words
            hh.append(element) #------ add the word to the list
            hh.sort() #--------------- organize the list
print(hh) #--------------------------- print the list of unique words
```

`hh` will be a list of all the unique words in the file.

The best way to work with files in Python is to use Context Managers.
Python Context Manager documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

You should probably use:

```
filename = input("Enter file name: ")
unique_words = list()
with open(filename, "r") as file: # 'with' Context Manager
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()
        for word in line:
            if word not in unique_words:
                unique_words.append(word)
                unique_words.sort()
print(unique_words)
```